# What does a addActionListener do?

Tags: java, button

I have the following code:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Clear");
button.addActionListener(this);
```

As far as I understand, I create a button on which it is written "Clear". Then I have to associate an action with this button (what will happen if the button is pressed) and it is done by `addActionListener`. Is it right?

But what I do not understand is where the action is specified. The press of the button should clear text area and, as far as I understand, there should be somewhere a code which clear the text area. But in the given example there is only "this" in the arguments of the **`addActionListener()`**.

How does the program know that it should clear the text area when the button is pressed?

If it is needed, the full code is given [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/KeyEventDemoProject/src/events/KeyEventDemo.java).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An [`ActionListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) is a callback mechanism. Whenever a control it is added to fires an `ActionEvent`, the `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method will be invoked.

> What I do not understand is where the actionPerformed is called. I see that it is defined within the class but there is no place where this method is called.

This is called by the internal mechanisms of the UI component. Conceptually, you can think of the code looking a bit like this:

```
public class Button {
  private final List<ActionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener>();

  public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
    listeners.add(l);
  }

  public void click() {
    ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(this, 0, "click");
    for (ActionListener l : listeners) {
      l.actionPerformed(event);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So addActionListnener is a method within the button class?

Comment: In Java addActionListener is defined in AbstractButton which is the parent of JButton.

Answer (score 3):

Each [`JButton`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html), has an [`EventListenerList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html). Calling `addActionListener(this)` adds your [`ActionListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), a callback function named `actionPerformed()`, to the list. You can see an outline of the code that calls your method [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html). The actual `fireActionPerformed()` method is in [`AbstractButton`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html). A [`JButton`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) is a [`JComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), which you can [see listed](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/class-use/EventListenerList.html) among the various classes that use the event listener list mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You call `button.addActionListener( this )`, because `this` implements the interface [`ActionListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html). When the button is clicked, the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` (defined by the interface and implemented by your class) is called.

Comment: What I do not understand is where the actionPerformed is called. I see that it is defined within the class but there is no place where this method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the mechanism of UI event handling is the JVM queue's events, and each type of event has its subscribers. When an event is fired, like the button is clicked, the JVM will accordingly delegate the processing to the event's subscriber. And this subscriber class has to define the method, or, event handler, to process the event.

In your case, when calling

```
button.addActionListener(this);
```

the code actually subscribes this KeyEventDemo instance to the event of type click. Then, when the button is clicked, the KeyEventDemo's method of actionPerformed will be triggered.