# two textfield update each other

Tags: java

I try to convert data but without clicking on a button, 
When I enter the data in the 1st textfield nothing happens

```
JTextField textC = new JTextField() ;
  JTextField textF = new JTextField() ;
  labelC.setText("Celsius");
  labelF.setText("Fahrenheit");

ActionListener textFieldCListener = new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String value = textC.getText();
    try {
        float valC = new Float(value);
        float valF = valC * 1.8f + 32;
        textF.setText(Float.toString(valF));
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        textF.setText("");
        textC.setText("");
    }
}};
```

Comment: you need add textFieldCListener into your textfield

Answer (score 1):

You should add `ActionListener` to your `JTextField` object.

```
textC.addActionListener(textFieldCListener);
```

See this: [What addActionListener does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167751/what-addactionlistener-does)

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`textC.addActionListener(textFieldCListener);`